# Cordova FCM push notification Not receiving data in background

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-push for receiving push notification in android devices

Here mine doubts (For android)

1)When app is in foreground every thing work fine push comes

2)When app is in background notification show in system tray and when I click on notification on('notification') will call and passes data

**So If I don't click on notification when app is in background
 and when app start  on('notification') won't call and notification data will not pass to the app.**

**Then how to get notification data.**

Comment: Did you get solution for this ? I'm also facing the same problem so.

Comment: @Vasanth did you find any solution for this? and I manage to get some workaround for this problem.